# how to draw a circle and move it as an animation in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, drawing, geometry

I would like to draw a simple circle and move it to the defined position on X,Y axis by coding.

For example;

There will be 2 buttons on WPF window and there will be a circle on 0,0(x,y). When I clicked on the 1st button, it will go to X = 150 and Y= 40. But the shape has to go there smoothly. I mean I dont want it to be disapear at the current position and appear on the defined position. I want it to go there. How should I do this? Can you explain me the steps? and if possible some example code ?

UPDATED CODE:

```
    int X = 0;
    int Y = 0;

    public bool inside = true;

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (inside)
        {
            DoubleAnimation animatex = new DoubleAnimation();
            animatex.To = X++;
            // animatex.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            // animatex.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
            el.BeginAnimation(Canvas.LeftProperty, animatex);

            DoubleAnimation animatey = new DoubleAnimation();
            animatey.To = Y++;
            // animatey.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
            el.BeginAnimation(Canvas.TopProperty, animatey);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xaml is something like 
`<Canvas>
            <Ellipse Width="10" Height="10" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" Fill="Black" x:Name="el"/>
        </Canvas>`
Click event of button is something like this

[image]

Hope this will work. I have tried it and it worked.

Comment: See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) about how to format code blocks. And you will certainly not repeat the animation forever, right? The circle shall simply move once to the target position.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. For Clemens; Actually, I will improve the code and I will make 4 arrows, up right left down and whenever I click one of them, It will go forever untill I end the movement with another button. It seems that I will increase animatex and animatey one by one in if loop

Comment: @ Ethicallogics or others: Can you check what I am doing wrong in the code updated by me above. I want circle to move until I change the if condition. But it doesnt work like that. It works everytime I click on the button.

Answer (score 0):

Or in XAML only:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="Move it">
            <Button.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click" >
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetName="theEllipse" Duration="00:00:05">
                            <DoubleAnimation From="-5" To="145" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)"/>
                            <DoubleAnimation From="-5" To="35" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Button.Triggers>
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
    <Border Margin="10" Grid.Row="1">
        <Canvas>
            <Ellipse x:Name="theEllipse" Width="10" Height="10" Fill="BlueViolet" Canvas.Left="-5" Canvas.Top="-5" />
        </Canvas>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Search for information on the use of Storyboard here or elsewhere.

Comment: Can you check what I am doing wrong in the code updated by me above. I want circle to move until I change the if condition. But it doesnt work like that. It works everytime I click on the button. Thank you.

Comment: Samet, it's not good practice to ask a question, and then change it after you've had one or more helpful or correct answers.  Please accept an answer and pose a new question.

Comment: ok, Thanks. I didnt know it. here is the other link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9366754/moving-a-drawn-circle-to-settled-position-in-c-sharp-wpf